# List file paths of a specific folder

Tags: python

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter
def listar_arquivos_diretorio(diretorio):
    arquivos = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(diretorio):
        for file in files:
            caminho = os.path.join(root, file)
            arquivos.append(caminho)
    return arquivos

    def criar_pdf_caminhos(arquivos, nome_arquivo):
    pdf = PdfWriter()
    for caminho in arquivos:
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.add_text(10, 10, caminho)

    with open(nome_arquivo, 'wb') as file:
        pdf.write(file)

diretorio = 'D:\Leandro'
arquivos = listar_arquivos_diretorio(diretorio)
nome_arquivo_pdf = 'D:\Leandro\a.pdf'

criar_pdf_caminhos(arquivos, nome_arquivo_pdf)
```

The code above would have the purpose of identifying files from a specific folder, listing the path of each existing file in the selected folder and creating a PDF with all the paths of each file, but something in the code is not allowing me to create this file.

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes.  `'\a'` is the ASCII bell character.  Either use `r'D:\Leandro\a.pdf'` or `'D:/Leandro/a.pdf'` or `'D:\\Leandro\\a.pdf'`.

Comment: The issue in your code seems to be with the indentation. The criar_pdf_caminhos function is defined within the listar_arquivos_diretorio function.

Comment: @xFranko That may just be a copying error for that `def` line, since the rest of it isn't indented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, file path list can use pathlib, very convenient.

```py
from pathlib import Path

from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter


def listar_arquivos_diretorio(diretorio):
    return [str(i) for i in Path(diretorio).rglob("*")]


def criar_pdf_caminhos(arquivos, nome_arquivo):
    pdf = PdfWriter()
    for caminho in arquivos:
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.add_text(10, 10, caminho)

    with open(nome_arquivo, "wb") as file:
        pdf.write(file)


diretorio = r"D:\Leandro"
arquivos = listar_arquivos_diretorio(diretorio)
nome_arquivo_pdf = r"D:\Leandro\a.pdf"

criar_pdf_caminhos(arquivos, nome_arquivo_pdf)
```